# How to compile C program on command line using MinGW?

Tags: c, windows, gcc, command-line, mingw

What command does one have to enter at the command line in Windows 7 to compile a basic C program?

Like I am literally wondering what you type in the command prompt, to compile a .c file.

I tried:

```
> gcc foo.c
```

But it says:

```
'gcc' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
 operable program or batch file.
```

I also tried:

```
> minGW foo.c
```

But I got back:

```
 'minGW' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
  operable program or batch file.
```

I have a path environment variable set to where MinGW is installed:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin
```

I can't really find any information on where I'm going wrong, and can't find anything in the official MinGW documentation, as it seems like this is something so simple, sort of an embarrassing question, that it's figured people know what to do?

Comment: I have a small program called test.c that i want to compile from the command line in Windows. I cd to the right directory where its located but the gcc command returns not recognized command, make as well.

Comment: @CodyGray Your link seems broken. Would you please update it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It indicates it couldn't find `gcc.exe`.

> I have a path environment variable set to where MinGW is installed

Maybe you haven't set the path correctly?

```
echo %path%
```

does that include the path to gcc.exe? Otherwise, compilation is similar to Unix:

```
gcc filename.c -o filename
```

Comment: Echo %path% returns C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin and in bin is gcc.exe , matches exactly where its located?

Comment: 'gcc' is not recognized as in internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: what happens if you cd to `C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin` and type in the command `gcc --version`?

Comment: Well when i do that gcc --version pulls up all the correct info and is ready to compile. Putting my .c files into that folder seems like a pain, i try to put in the path variable again and restart but is there any reason its not working? Perhaps i should move or reinstall minGW somewhere else?

Comment: Maybe, try to uninstall mingW and install it in C:\mingw and set the path and see again if it works.

Comment: Okay, it seems restarting the computer after resetting the path environment variable fixed things, works fine now. Thanks.

Comment: @kingsindian It is a known fact (issue) that MinGW has issues with paths that contain spaces. So that's why it works in the folder C:\mingw

Comment: @l3x Re-installing MinGW in the folder `C:\MinGW` and then setting the path variable to that location as well, like you suggested, fixed the problem. Thanks again!

Answer (score 11):

I've had this problem and couldn't find why it kept happening. The reason is simple: Once you have set up the environment paths, you have to close the CMD window, and open it again for it be aware of new environment paths.

Comment: This. I opened 5 blogs, 10 new articles, checked path 20 times and what I forgot was to close and reopen CMD to reflect the changed variables...

Answer (score 4):

**First:**

Add your minGW's bin folder directory ( ex: **C\mingw64\bin** ) in System variables => Path. [visual example](https://prnt.sc/m56o71)

---

**Compile:**

**.c:** gcc filename.c -o desire

**.cpp:** g++ filename.cpp -o desire

---

**Run:**

desire/ ***or*** ./desire

Answer (score 1):

Just set the environment variable to the EXACT path to gcc.exe like this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe
```

Comment: Never install mingw on path which contain spaces such as "Program File"

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same error message after unpacking MinGW archives to `C:\MinGW` and setting the path to environment variable as `C:\MinGW\bin;`.

When I try to compile I get this error!

> gcc: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory

I finally figured out that some of the downloaded archives were reported broken while unpaking them to `C:\MinGW` (yet I ignored this initially). 
Once I deleted the broken files and re-downloaded the whole archives again from SourceForge, unpacked them to C:\MinGW successfully the error was gone, and the compiler worked fine and output my desired `hello.exe`.

I ran this:

```
gcc hello.c -o hello
```

The result result was this (a blinking underscore):

_

Answer (score 1):

I once had this kind of problem installing MinGW to work in Windows, even after I added the right System PATH in my Environment Variables.

After days of misery, I finally stumbled on a thread that recommended uninstalling the original MinGW compiler and deleting the `C:\MinGW` folder and installing TDM-GCC MinGW compiler which can be found [here](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/download).

You have options of choosing a 64/32-bit installer from the download page, and it creates the environment path variables for you too.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with .c files that contained functions (not `main()` of my program). For example, my header files were "fact.h" and "fact.c", and my main program was "main.c" so my commands were like this:

```
E:\proj> gcc -c fact.c
```

Now I had an object file of fact.c (fact.o). after that:

```
E:\proj>gcc -o prog.exe fact.o main.c
```

Then my program (prog.exe) was ready to use and worked properly. I think that `-c` after `gcc` was important, because it makes object files that can attach to make the program we need. Without using `-c`, gcc ties to find main in your program and when it doesn't find it, it gives you this error.

Answer (score 1):

You can permanently include the directory of the MinGW file, by clicking on My Computer, Properties, Advanced system settings, Environment variables, then edit and paste your directory.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the `%PATH%` you may enter your [msys](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS) shell. In standard msys and mingw installation gcc is in path, so you can run `gcc` or `which gcc`.

I have a batch file `sh.bat` on my Windows 7, in %PATH%:

```
C:\lang\msys\bin\sh.exe --login %*
```

Whenever I want to use gcc I enter cmd, then `sh`, then `gcc`. I find it very convenient.

When working with linux originated software avoid spaced directories like `Program Files`. Install them rather to `Program_Files`. The same regards to tools that you may want to run from msys environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you pasted your text into the path variable and added a whitespace before the semicolon, you should delete that and add a backslash at the end of the directory (;C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin

Answer (score 0):

Where is your `gcc`?

My `gcc` is in "C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin\".

```
"C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin\gcc" -c "foo.c"
"C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin\gcc" "foo.o" -o "foo 01.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am quite late answering this question (5 years to be exact) but I hope this helps someone.

I suspect that this error is because of the environment variables instead of GCC. When you set a new environment variable you need to open a new Command Prompt! This is the issue 90% of the time (when I first downloaded GCC I was stuck with this for 3 hours!) If this isn't the case, you probably haven't set the environment variables properly or you are in a folder with spaces in the name.

Once you have GCC working, it can be a hassle to compile and delete every time. If you don't want to install a full ide and already have python installed, try this github project: https://github.com/sophiadm/notepad-is-effort
It is a small IDE written with tkinter in python. You can just copy the source code and save it as a .py file

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10, similar steps can be followed in other versions of windows.

Right Click on "My Computer" select Properties, Goto Advanced System Settings -> Advanced -> Select "Environment Variables.." .

Find "Path" select it and choose edit option -> Click on New and add "C:\MinGW\bin" (or the location of gcc.exe, if you have installed at some other location) -> Save and restart command prompt. Gcc should work.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 11, I installed MinGW-w64 using the Scoop package manager.
Then I fired up MSYS2 from the Start Menu and installed the `mingw-w64-x86-toolchain` package.

After that, the `gcc` executable could be launched by specifying `/mingw64/bin/gcc`.