# Compile on Windows to Linux using MinGW?

Tags: c++, c, mingw

Is there a way to compile Linux programs on Windows using MinGW and cmd? I really need to do that. And how will I have to link libraries?

Edit: The Libraries I want to link are SFML. They should be compatible on Linux and MacOSX. Is there at least a simlar Compiler that can compile to those three platforms?

Comment: It's be easier to just install e.g. VMWare or VirtualBox, set up a Linux VM, and do your development (or at least compilation and linking) inside the VM.

Comment: May be [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10661663/how-to-compile-c-program-on-command-line-using-mingw) can help you

Comment: You can't do it with the mingw provided compilers but it is possible to build a cross-compiler toolchain and use that, it is, however, a huge pain. As already stated much easier to use a virtual machine (or if on windows 10 the Linux for windows package).

Comment: MinGW is a version (port) of GCC which purpose is exclusively to build programs for Windows. You can actually use it to build windows using linux, which is opposite of what you want to do :-) This is called cross-compilation. You need to find the right cross-compiler if you want to do this the other way. Or just use a virtual machine like previous comments say. It would help us to narrow the solution if you tell us why do you need to use Windows to compile for Linux.

Comment: What libraries you need to link. Are they written by you? Do you have Linux versions of them or they are native Windows libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MinGW compiles to executables referencing the Windows NT ABI. A program compiled in MinGW will, generally speaking, not be usable on Linux. You want a cross-compiler that goes the other direction, i.e., runs on Windows but compiles to executables referencing the Linux ABI. Alternatively, just get a crappy old computer, boot it into Arch and compile your code there.